# Не срабатывает перенаправление (header) в файле PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте! Буду крайне благодарен за совет. Проблема следующая, есть html-форма регистрации. Мне нужно сделать проверку введенных данных на сервере(конкретно логина) на его уникальность. С этой целью я отменяю стандартное поведение формы при отправке и переключаю управление на js в котором формирую ajax - запрос на php файл, код которого привожу ниже. Короче, чтобы долго не расписывать - не срабатывает header, который должен при прохождении проверки перенаправлять пользователя на его страницу.

```
<?php
//Сюда перемещаются данные после регистрации
require "database_connection.php"; // Подключаем файл с алгоритмом входа в базу данных
require "current_date.php";
$new_user_name = $_REQUEST['create_user_name'];
$new_user_password = $_REQUEST['create_user_password'];
if (!$new_user_name || !$new_user_password){
    exit("You must enter the name and password!");
}elseif ( preg_match("/ /", $new_user_name) ){  //Проверка на то, что пользователь не вводил пробелы в логине
    exit("The login should be one word");
}else{
    $users_names_query = "SELECT login FROM users;"; 
    $get_users_names = mysql_query($users_names_query); //Находим все зарегистрированные ранее логины в БД
    while($user_name = mysql_fetch_row($get_users_names)){
        if($new_user_name === $user_name[0]){         //перебираем их и сравниваем с введенным в форме регистрации
            $flag = 1; 
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($flag != 1){
        $add_user_query = "INSERT INTO users(
                          login, pasword)
                          VALUES(
                          '{$new_user_name}','{$new_user_password}');";
        $query_result = mysql_query($add_user_query);  //Добавляем нового пользователя в таблицу пользователей БД
        if(!$query_result){
            die("Unfortunately, some mistake has appeared with {$add_user_query} :" . mysql_error());
        };
        header("Location: show_user_table.php?user_id=" . mysql_insert_id()); //Переходим в файл вывода таблицы и переносим туда id последнего введенного запроса
        exit; 
    }else{
        $marker = array('flag' => $flag);
        echo json_encode($marker);
        exit;    
    }
}
```

Чтобы сразу снять некоторые моменты: файлы в начале (database_connection.php и current_date.php) Влиять на него не могут, так как раньше, напрямую (при отправке формы) этот же файл прекрасно с ними работал. Думаю, что проблема как раз таки в ajax запросе, но вот знаний на данный момент не хватает для понимания сути проблемы. А вот сам ajax запрос:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET','registration_page.php?create_user_name=' + name + '&create_user_password=' + password, true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        while (this.readyState != 4){
                return;
        }
        if(this.status != 200){
                alert (request.status + ':' + this.statusText);
        }else{
                var mas = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        if(mas.flag == 1){
            clear.innerHTML = "This user is already exist!";
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: что то обычно сначала обработчик навешивают, а потом запрос отправляют, а не наоборот. зы: почему вы не пользуете jquery и PDO ?

Comment: в любом случае смотрите, срабатывает ли ваш обработчик аякса вообще, если да, то смотрите код ответа в инструментах браузера. Если приходит 301, то получите ваш алерт, если не приходит, то в тексте будет ошибка типа `headers already sent`, тогда ковыряйте пхп код. и да, провертье добавляется ли юзер.

Comment: вообще, если у вас скрипт отдает json, то он всегда должен отдавать JSON, а не в одном случае json, в другом строку текста, в третьем редирект. Отдавайте json со статусом выполнения, кодом ошибки, строкой урл для перенаправления.

Comment: Уточнение: вы заголовок редиректа пытаетесь скормить в ответ на ajax запрос? А вы уверены, что ajax вообще смотрит на этот заголовок? Или, может, сам ajax запрос идёт по редиректу? Почему он должен оказывать влияние на страницу инициировавшую ajax запрос? Если вы хотите обрабатывать форму через js - то и редирект делайте силами js.

Comment: teran,  PDO и jquery не использую по той причине, что пока только учу php и js. Сейчас мне важно понять сами принципы их работы, прежде чем переходить на фреймворки. Тех ошибок, о которых вы говорите нет, их я проверил в первую очередь. Юзер добавляется.

Comment: Мелкий, нет, не уверен, поэтому к вам и обращаюсь. Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит "редирект делайте силами js"? Имеется в виду, переадресация при помощи window.location.href ?

Comment: Да, заголовки уже были отправлены, что бы перенаправить пользователя на другую страницу вы можете следовать ответу Артемия или отправить путь пользователю и сделать редирект на JS, например: `window.location.replace("/show_user_table.php?user_id=1");`

Comment: Кстати вы говорите юзер добавляется и проблем, якобы, нету. Юзер добавляется ибо это не ошибка, а предупреждение о том что заголовки уже отправлены(почитайте про заголовки подробнее что бы понять). Весь код выполняется, заголовок же про редирект игнорируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заголовки отправляются сервером в самом начале соединения. Подробнее про это [тут](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Если вы хотите сделать редирект на чистом PHP то следуйте ответу Артемия или сделайте дополнительную страницу `redirect.php?redirect_url=[url]` которая и будет перенаправлять пользователя далее, правда вариант не из лучших.

Как другой вариант можно отправить пользователю ссылку по AJAX куда нужно идти и переадресовать туда. Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
window.location.replace("/show_user_table.php?user_id=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброе время суток. Проблема заключается в том, что функция header() используется для отправки HTTP заголовка. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML тэгов, пустых строк и т.п.
Данную проблему решит две функции php:

```
<?php
ob_start();//В начале коде



ob_flush();//В конце кода
?>
```

Comment: нормальный код решает эту проблему лучше

Comment: это как ты либо нормально ходишь на горшок, или гоняешь в подгузнике, подгузы в целом тоже решают проблему. но их обычно либо в малом возрасте носят, либо по медицинским показаниям.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо всем за советы! Воспользовался советами Telion-a, Мелкого и terana. Моя ошибка была в том, что я пытался выполнить редирект из того же файла, который вызывался ajax-запросом. Всего-то и нужно было что вернуть тем же аяксом в js статус логина (принят или нет) и id нового пользователя. Если логин принят, то функцией `window.location.replace` перенаправить пользователя на его страницу! 
Может кто-то еще подскажет как тут можно поблагодарить людей? А то пишу я здесь нечасто, и не в курсе...

Comment: Уже поблагодарили :) Можно ставить плюсы(стрелочка вверх), минусы(вниз) и вот галочка как лучший ответ.